# mysql-server-5.5 Error

Tags: server, apt, package-management, dpkg, mysql

```
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.52-0+deb7u1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server-5.5:
 mysql-server-5.5 depends on mysql-client-5.5 (>= 5.5.52-0+deb7u1); however:
  Package mysql-client-5.5 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server

Current status: 1 broken [+1].
```

Comment: How long have you had this Ubuntu install and when it the last time you updated the repositories with `sudo apt update`?

Answer (score 0):

sudo dpkg --configure -a
if doesn't work then

```
 sudo apt-get autoremove mysql-server
 sudo apt-get autoclean
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server
```

If it doesn't work then remove sources.list file.and create new sources.list...

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

[image]
This will open software-properties-gtk and a newsources.list will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

Tick all the boxes then click on Revert then click close.

Need to restore default repositories

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

(it is good practice to backup this file before installing to recover if such things happen)